# Bing Search API Azure Marketplace Authentication (Delphi + Indy)

Tags: delphi, azure, delphi-xe, bing, indy10

Can anyone point in the right direction? I'm trying to perform web searches sung the new Bing API, but with the below code I keep getting "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". The same request works well under the browser (leaving username blank and providing the key under password inside the   prompt box).

```
var
  IdHTTP1 : TIdHTTP;
  uri : string;
  myIOhandler : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  myIOhandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  with myIOhandler do
  begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      host := '';
  end;

  IdHTTP1:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent:= 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; IndyLibrary)';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/javascript';
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';

  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects:= True;
  IdHTTP1.ConnectTimeout:= 10000;
  IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout:= 10000;
  IdHTTP1.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication:= True;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication:= TIdBasicAuthentication.Create;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Username:= '';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Password:= APIKey;//Encode64(APIKey);//Encode64(APIKey+':'+APIKey)
  IdHTTP1.IOHandler:= myIOHandler;

  uri:= 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?'+
          'Query=%27'+ query_text +'%27&$format=JSON&$top=50&$skip=0';
  s:= IdHTTP1.Get(uri);
```

MS documentation is very poor.

Comment: Are you sure that the HTTP Basic Auth should work with an empty username? And is the query_text correctly "URL encoded"?

Comment: According to the Migration Guide Document: "Leave the user-name field empty and enter your account key in the password field."

Comment: Just for testing, I am not using any characters that will need encoding. I'll deal with that later. The same string works in the browser.

Comment: To find the differences in the requests of Indy and the browser you can use a HTTP proxy like Fiddler

Comment: I believe the problem is in the authentication, as you can see in my code I've tried to use Base64 encoding. There are some related posts with java and they use base64.encode like base64Encode(key:key). Once again not much information available... ) the old Bing API will stop working tomorrow)

Comment: Take out `TIBasicAuthentication` completely. Let `TIdHTTP` manage the `Request.Authentication` property internally for you. Use the `Request.UserName` and `Request.Password` properties instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` handles `Basic` authentication automatically for you.  Simply set `IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := True` and then fill in the `IdHTTP1.Request.Username` and `IdHTTP1.Request.Password` properties. You do not need to deal with `TIdBasicAuthentication` directly.

If you want to support other authentications, such as NTLM, simply add the relavant `IdAuthentication...` unit(s), or the `IdAllAuthentication` unit, to your `uses` clause.

You can also implement your own custom `TIdAuthentication`-derived class if you want to support custom authentications that Indy does not natively support.  You can either call `RegisterAuthenticationMethod()` so `TIdHTTP` can use your custom class automatically, or you can use the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event to assign the class manually on a per-request basis.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the username. With basic authentication you need to send a header that looks like this:

```
Authorization: Basic BASE64ENC(username:password)
```

Since the username is empty in your case, you are actually sending this:

```
Authorization: Basic BASE64ENC(:password)
```

Even though the documentation says to leave the username blank, this only applies to when you visit the page through the browser. Take a look at the code samples by the end of the document, you'll see that in many of those examples both the username and the password are the account key:

```
bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);
```

I suggest you do the same in your code:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication:= TIdBasicAuthentication.Create;
IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Username:= APIKey;
IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Password:= APIKey;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it's not working. I'm going to replace my OpenSSL libraries and tweak with the SSL options, maybe they have something to do with it.

Comment: TIdHTTP handles Basic Authentication automatically for you.  Simply set `IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := True` and then fill in the `IdHTTP1.Request.Username` and `IdHTTP1.Request.Password` properties. You do not need to deal with `TIdBasicAuthentication` directly.